# trying to get contents of all tables having a class attribute

Tags: regex, coldfusion

using **coldfusion**, i am fetching all tables using the `RematchNoCase` command

```
<cfset data = REMatchNoCase('<table.*?</*.table*.>','#header#')>
```

i am getting the values as an array, but i want to get only thos tables who has a class of grids like

```
<cfset data = REMatchNoCase('<table class="grids".*?</*.table*.>','#header#')>
```

but i am getting an empty array with the last try

Comment: why don't you use Jsoup to achieve the above.

Comment: What constraints? JSoup is the perfect tool for this.

Comment: It will never cease to amaze me when people are given the perfect solution to a problem and say, 'Thanks, but no thanks'. While the regex given may work, there is a better than good chance that it will not catch everything every time. JSoup is the best solution for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Imagine this scenario: A person has 2 pieces of wood that need to be fastened to each other using a straight, smooth piece of metal. All this person needs is a way to driving the piece of metal into the tow pieces of wood using striking blows. You reply, 'A hammer is the perfect tool for the job.' And in return you hear, 'Thanks, but no thanks. I will use something else completely ill suited for the job at hand.'\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following work?

```
<cfset data = ReMatchNoCase("<table[^>""]+class=""grids""[^>]>.*?</table>", header) />
```